# PlayFramework, Scala for loop in view layer. How to get index value?

Tags: scala, playframework

I have loop in view tier of playframework application.

```
@for(art <- currentPage.getArticles()) {

}
```

Where method: `getArticles()` returns object of: `List<ArticleI>`.

I would like to get index value inside this loop.

How can I achive this?

I use `Play 2.2.6` with `Java` and `Eclipse IDE`.

The eclipse plugin for play is very very bad. If it would work, I think that with intelisense I will figure this out on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index in this way:

```
@for((art, index) <- currentPage.getArticles()) {
  <p>Element @index is @art</p>
}
```

Note: The index starts with 0, so if you want to display a 1 instead:

```
@for((art, index) <- currentPage.getArticles()) {
  <p>Element @{index+1} is @art</p>
}
```

I hope, that helps you...

Comment: Doesen't work. Compilation error.

Comment: Try the loop without content, is there still an error?

Answer (score 0):

Use @index

```
@for((art, index) <- currentPage.getArticles()) {
    <li>Item @index is @art</li>
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I am getting an error: `Index.scala.html:26: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
[error]  found   : (T1, T2)
[error]  required: cms.models.i.ArticleI
[error] @for((art, index) <- currentPage.getArticles()) {
[error]      ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
`